# Trying to extract a namespace value from an xmltype

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

my BLOB (converted to XMLType) contains the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf"><S2SCTScf:SndgInst>EBAPFRPA</S2SCTScf:SndgInst><S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>NWBKGB2X</S2SCTScf:RcvgInst><S2SCTScf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTScf:SrvcId><S2SCTScf:TstCode>P</S2SCTScf:TstCode><S2SCTScf:FType>SCF</S2SCTScf:FType><S2SCTScf:FileRef>NSCT220610000729</S2SCTScf:FileRef><S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>IND</S2SCTScf:RoutingInd><S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>2022-06-10</S2SCTScf:FileBusDt><S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>11</S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo><S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02"><GrpHdr><MsgId>NSCT2206100007290000000000000000001</MsgId><CreDtTm>2022-06-10T09:52:54</CreDtTand
```

I wish to use SQL to extract the namespace value :

```
<S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
```

How would I do that  - I tried XMLQuery but couldn't get it to work.

Many thanks

Comment: You can get node attributes via XMLQuery, but `xmlns` isn't a normal attribute. Why do you need to get it - will you be validating the XML perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FLOWR to delete the child elements and just return that single element:

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         'declare namespace S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf";
         copy $e := /S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf/S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf
         modify (
           for $i in $e/*
             return delete node $i
         )
         return $e'
         PASSING value RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getStringVal() AS xmlns_element
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf">
  <S2SCTScf:SndgInst>EBAPFRPA</S2SCTScf:SndgInst>
  <S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>NWBKGB2X</S2SCTScf:RcvgInst>
  <S2SCTScf:SrvcId>SCT</S2SCTScf:SrvcId>
  <S2SCTScf:TstCode>P</S2SCTScf:TstCode>
  <S2SCTScf:FType>SCF</S2SCTScf:FType>
  <S2SCTScf:FileRef>NSCT220610000729</S2SCTScf:FileRef>
  <S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>IND</S2SCTScf:RoutingInd>
  <S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>2022-06-10</S2SCTScf:FileBusDt>
  <S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>11</S2SCTScf:FileCycleNo>
  <S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02">
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>NSCT2206100007290000000000000000001</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2022-06-10T09:52:54</CreDtTm>
    </GrpHdr>
  </S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
</S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf>') FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | XMLNS_ELEMENT |
> | --- |
> | <S2SCTScf:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.02"/> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8db7d9b3c78b0107b92b2e479a6bf59f)*

Answer (score 0):

As this and the XML in your previous question both have the `GrpHdr` node, and you were trying to the `MsgId` from it then, you might simply be trying to get the namespace so you can pass it back into another XMLQuery call.

If that is the case then you could ignore the namespaces and use wildcards:

```
with q1 (Tdata) as (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) from paymentinterchange
)
select XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:MsgId/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval()
from q1
```

which would get the message ID from this XML or the previous example. I've changed the character set to AL32UTF8 to match this XML's UTF-8 declaration, which could be a problem if you have a mix of encodings in your data.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=144d6df465b71acb54c43c1e15c12370) with the old and new XML.